# What does checking if a generic tuple extends an expression in brackets achieve?

Tags: typescript

So I have this factory pattern where I can create new Instances of my Service Classes with the correct typings. For this I need a type where I extract a single key:

```
type ServiceSingleKeys<T> = [T] extends (
  T extends 'foo' | 'oof' ? [T] : never
)
  ? T
  : never;
```

The code above is from a code snippet I found, but the snippet isn't explained. I sadly lost the link to the snippet so I cannot provide the link here.

Here is a more detailed reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ha1bha?file=index.ts

What does the `[T]` do? (Answered in comment --> Tuple)

What effect gets achieved by first checking if `[T]` extends `(T extends ServiceKeys ? [T] : never)`? How does this work or in other words what is this doing? In my understanding I can achieve the same effect from the type with this

```
type ServiceSingleKeys<T> = T extends 'foo' | 'oof' ? T : never;
```

Comment: `[T]` is just a tuple with a single element with type `T`.

Comment: @Blackhole Okay, thanks. This answers one of my questions :)

Comment: @TobiasS. Functional difference yes, but I don't understand what checking `[T]` extends `(T extends ServiceKeys ? [T] : never)` achieves or in other words what this does.

Comment: Please include your [mre] as plain text within the question post itself; having an external link is a nice supplement but it does not suffice.  Please ask a single question in this post, or clearly indicate which of your several questions is the primary one (such that an answer to the primary question constitutes an answer to the whole thing; if that isn't true, then you should separate out your questions into multiple posts).

Comment: Thanks!  That code example doesn't seem to be minimal; presumably you only need to write `type ServiceKeys = "foo" | "oof"; type ServiceSingleKeys<T> = [T] extends (T extends ServiceKeys ? [T] : never)  ? T  : never;` or maybe even `type ServiceSingleKeys<T> = [T] extends (T extends "foo" | "oof" ? [T] : never)  ? T  : never;`... if the rest of the code is actually important for the question, can you explain how?  Right now my eyes are sliding off of everything except those two lines.

Comment: As for primary question: it's hard to divine the purpose of that code since it has unmotivated complications in it.  The line `type SSK<T> = [T] extends (T extends ServiceKeys ? [T] : never) ? T : never` is functionally identical to `type SSK<T> = [T] extends [ServiceKeys] ? T : never` but not to `type SSK<T> = T extends ServiceKeys ? T : never`. I can explain what both of the latter versions do and do not do, but I have no idea why someone would write the longer version... is it trial and error?  Is it really the case that *you* wrote it and are now asking other people what you meant by it?

Comment: For the first question. I added it for context but I could remove it if you would like me to do so. As for the second question, I found this in a code snippet but it wasn't explained there, that's why I am asking here.

Comment: *I* would prefer it if the code example were actually minimal, but maybe someone else would appreciate the context?  But I think "here's some code I found, why did someone write it this way" is opinion based and therefore inappropriate for stack overflow.  I can tell you what it seems to be doing and how to rewrite it more simply, but not why someone wrote it that way.  I'd be more comfortable if the question were [edit]ed to be clearly within the scope of what a SO question is supposed to be.

Comment: I edited the question now. I don't wan't to know why someone did it in the snipped like this. I don't understand how `[T] extends (
  T extends 'foo' | 'oof' ? [T] : never
)
  ? T
  : never;` works or in your words I don't know what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
type ServiceSingleKeys<T> = [T] extends (
  T extends 'foo' | 'oof' ? [T] : never
) ? T : never;
```

has the effect of checking whether or not the entire input type `T` is assignable to the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"foo" | "oof"`.  If it is, it returns `T`.  If not, it returns `never`.  So you get this behavior:

```
type A = ServiceSingleKeys<"foo" | "oof"> // "foo" | "oof"
type B = ServiceSingleKeys<"foo"> // "foo"
type C = ServiceSingleKeys<"foo" | "bar"> // never
```

Type `A` and `B` are the same as their inputs, because `"foo" | "oof"` and `"foo"` are both assignable to `"foo" | "oof"`.  type `C` is `never`, because `"foo" | "bar"` is *not* assignable to `"foo" | "oof"`.

---

This could be rewritten more simply as:

```
type ServiceSingleKeys<T> = [T] extends ['foo' | 'oof'] ? T : never;

type A = ServiceSingleKeys<"foo" | "oof"> // "foo" | "oof"
type B = ServiceSingleKeys<"foo"> // "foo"
type C = ServiceSingleKeys<"foo" | "bar"> // never
```

And indeed, this is how I would have written such a type if I needed to.  I cannot say why the original version is written how it is.  My *guess* would be that it was assembled via trial and error.  (If it turns out that there is some edge case where these two versions are not functionally equivalent, then *maybe* that edge case is the reason, but without more information I'm skeptical).

You cannot remove the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) wrapper from the check without changing the behavior:

```
type NotServiceSingleKeys<T> = T extends 'foo' | 'oof' ? T : never;

type A = NotServiceSingleKeys<"foo" | "oof"> // "foo" | "oof"
type B = NotServiceSingleKeys<"foo"> // "foo"
type C = NotServiceSingleKeys<"foo" | "bar"> // "foo" <-- difference
```

That's because a conditional type in which the checked type is a bare generic type parameter is a [*distributive* conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), where the input type is broken up into its individual union members before being evaluated, and the output is joined into a new union.  So `NotServiceSingleKeys<"foo" | "bar">` is evaluated as `NotServiceSingleKeys<"foo"> | NotServiceSingleKeys<"bar">` which becomes `"foo" | never` or just `"foo"`.

Distributive conditional types are often what people want to see (this allows you to get union-filtering behavior like [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)), but when it is undesirable, then the fix is usually to wrap both sides of the `extends` check in one-tuples.  The check `[T] extends ['foo' | 'oof']` is non-distributive because `[T]` is not a bare generic type parameter, but the check is similar because tuples are covariant (meaning that `[XXX]` is assignable to `[YYY]` if and only if `XXX` is assignable to `YYY`).  As it says in the above-linked [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

> Typically, distributivity is the desired behavior. To avoid that behavior, you can surround each side of the `extends` keyword with square brackets.

Again, my *guess* here is that the original version of the code was a trial-and-error attempt to apply that advice in order to prevent the check from being accidentally distributive.  If there is some other purpose to the particular nested conditional type in the question, I don't see it.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.7.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgPIBOAlgOZ6FFIAuAnjMgMoRUBuNRFxrA6GCAGkIbKAB4AKgD4kAXiQBteQF0kEAB4sIwACZQkACibMk83QaOmkAcgBmAezdOkAH2ceXXgD8GtpIAFzEEHy8VkgAlLFEwfKJ4ZHRVADc+LHsnEgAgqpIPPyCEMKi4lIysgBE7m51Pkh1-nXKAPSdrY3Nvm1uLnW5HMgAQsWlAkIiYpLScg0eHUjdvSuj+QDCU7wzFXPVi-V9LXUARiBUq+vAUTFMAL45RCTQcIhI4yDGAEoQADutEMjGseW4+3KlXmNTkSmKtn0hhMZlcHi8vic-iCNjS9wy2S2yCKamm0KOC1qyya53aXR6NP6rXaxO+ezKsyqVKWfQZGyabN2ZKhXNhJyZ5yuN35ktkAFp5UhjDQXC5eEZEM9XsRwB9yEgAcCaKCCOCxiVRYduXCFMo1JodMiHGZ1OjPC1sUMnDpkviHlkdUQIYUOQcYcdqWcBvS1ozoyyhiNzflJiLOdbxVGVrK+kKwxSbRKE5drrcegSYkQXjknkA)